# What does "walk you off a tower" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (2004)* movie, Harry Potter fell over 100 feet:

> Fred: What do you expect? He fell over 100 feet.
>
> Geroge (says to Ron): Let's **walk you off a tower** and see what  you
> look like.

What does "walk you off a tower" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "let us have you walk off a tower", then we'll see if you look better than Harry does.
In effect, it means "Of course he looks bad! He walked off a tower! Who wouldn't look bad after falling 100 feet?"

Comment: **walk off** means walk away with anger, but here Harry Potter **fell**, how is that related to each other??

Comment: @BobbyOmega You may want to read this answer again.

Comment: He's talking about if Ron fell from a tower
I.e. walking off the edge of a very tall building

Comment: "Walk you off a tower" = "cause you to walk off the edge of a tower". **Walk someone off something** probably isn't enough of an established phrase to be in the dictionary, but the meaning is clear to a native speaker.